# Facebook Like - Can we transfer them to other URL's?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

For example suppose I had 1000 Likes on this URL:

example.com/coolpage.php

But I wanted to rename the URL to:

example.com/domscoolpage.php

Can I transfer the Likes from the 1st to the 2nd in the same way you can transfer PageRank via 301s?

Cheers smile

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, you will have to start from scratch. You could 301 from the original liked URL to the new one though

Comment: Any documentation for that? Facebook will probably improve this sometime, how could we know that your answer is still valid?