# How to get top 30 most liked urls on my website (FQL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm upgrading my webshop and it involves doing some changes in my product url's (because of SEO optimizing). Since there doesn't seem to be anyway of migrating likes from one url to another and "tricking" the likes to the old url with 301 redirecting is out of the question, i was trying to get a list of the top 20-30 liked urls so i could then loop the result to find the amount of likes, shares etc.

I have already built a small script that finds the like, share etc count for a certain url, but i am unable to find out what the most liked url's are!

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Although migrating likes is not possible, why do you say 301 redirects are out of the question ? Is it a decision on your part to not do the redirects ? If not, here is a solution that was posted a while back - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o/10152342#10152342

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not easy. You'll need to build an FQL query like this:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count
FROM link_stat 
WHERE url IN ("example.com/url1", "example.com/url2", ... "example.com/urln")
ORDER BY like_count DESC
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve anything. I have no idea what the most liked url's are, and looping 16 000 url's in that sql is just... impossible