# Buying a custom domain without losing fb likes, comments and G+ +1

Tags: facebook, google-plus, blogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page’s Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-I-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-Facebook-likes-and-o)

I run this blog http://everythingyoumightneed.blogspot.comI am thinking of moving my blogspot blog to a custom domain. I did some research and I found out that if I do so I will lose all my G+ plusones and Facebook likes for my posts. Same thing with Facebook comments. (I have Facebook comment social plugin on each post of my blog)

My question is, whether there is a way, using to avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the url associated with the comments.  You can, however, modify the code on your new site so that each post points to the comments page for the old url.

on each page on the new domain this will associate the facebook comments with the old domain:

```
<fb:comments href="THE-OLD-URL"></fb:comments>
```

So for example for http://newdomain.com/thenewpage.html:

```
<fb:comments href="http://olddomain.com/theoldpage.html"></fb:comments>
```

To get this working, first get facebook comments working on your new site using the facebook documentation.  Once you have that working, you can put the code above anywhere on the page (I usually put it in the head somewhere).  That will tell facebook to use the old url instead.

This will apply to likes, comments, and everything else.

Comment: where shall I put this code?? also what about likes and +1s???

Comment: Sorry, I've never done the +1's.  This page seems to suggest that you can put an href attribute within the button, pointing to the old url.  https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url