# Preserve Facebook Likes, 301 Redirects, href tags, and canonical URLs

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page’s Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

We have recently moved our site from a custom CMS to Wordpress and we are trying desperately to preserve likes.

During development we simply pointed our Like buttons from the the new URL to the legacy URL via the href tag. Likes transferred fine.

```
<fb:like href='$url' send='false' layout='button_count' width='150' show_faces='false'></fb:like>
```

Where `$url` is the legacy URL

When we went live, all Likes reset to zero, I'm guessing at the same time we set up our 301 redirects via .htaccess.

What's odd is that I used the same procedure for the FB Comments box, and all comments have transferred over perfectly!

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="$url" data-width="500"></div>
```

Does anyone have any insight to this? Is there somewhere else I need to store the legacy url besides the href tag on the facebook like box?

For example, I notice the OG:url points to the current page, as evidenced by the FB debugger tool.

Perhaps the original URL needs to remain live - not just via 301?

Also note, that FB likes still work fine on pages that haven't been 301'ed. [This page, for example.](http://www.craftbeer.com/beer-studies/beer101-course)

[Here is an example](http://www.craftbeer.com/craft-beer-muses/should-the-shaker-pint-glass-go-away) of a legacy post with likes reset. The original url was : www.craftbeer.com/pages/stories/craft-beer-muses/show?title=should-the-shaker-pint-glass-go-away

New posts track likes just fine.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Have you checked this related answer here - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o/10152342#10152342 ?

Comment: Yes - looks like the same issue. What's still not clear to me is, does the old URL need to remain accessible? If so, why do my pages that have no 301 (and no longer remain at the old url) still retain likes?