# How do I migrate Facebook Comments from one site to another?

Tags: facebook, comments

Hi i'm The owner of a Facebook app with this ID: 187382088033833.
I've made new website, and i want to recover my old comments made with my application.

E.g. in this page, in the old version i got a lot of comments: http://www.youris.com/Environment/Bees/Bees_restored_to_health_in_Italy_after_this_springs_neonicotinoidfree_maize_sowing.kl

why now i can't see the old comments?
can you help me?

Comment: How were your comments collected before? The Comments social plugin? Are you using the same application ID? Did you change the Application settings to point to the new domain? I believe comments are tied to a specific domain & url, so migrating them to a new domain might be impossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Facebook [Comments Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) documentation, comments are tied to a URL for the page that they were made on. Migrating to a new domain, or moving your page to a new URL, without keeping your comment social plugin URL setting the same as what it was in the past, will cause you to lose your comments.

I would try changing your `href` setting on your plugin to the old URL for the page you're loading. You may have to maintain that old page as a redirect to the new page should Facebook try to verify it's existence before rendering the comments plugin, or should someone click a link that is published to their news feed so they get redirected to the appropriate place.

Comment: My point is this: i got an app with this ID 187382088033833, i got some changes on my app, for the July 15th changes.
The problem is that, if i see my moderation tool, i see all the comments, but if i try to insert the comment box on my site i can't see that.
EXAMPLE My page: http://www.youris.com/Society/Culture_and_Leisure/Images_from_the_Past.kl?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150244957149765_26151398_10151622217574765

has got some comments before, and now these comments are disapperead