# Facebook shares count after domain name change

Tags: facebook

I changed the domain name of my website one week ago. Everything seems to work except the fact that the Facebook shares count of my posts has been reset to zero.
I did a 301 redirect. Is there something else I should do ? Or do I need to wait a few more days?

Comment: Have you followed this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o/10152342#10152342

Comment: Thank you @deesarus it works