# I need clarifications on how to properly implement og:url and rel=canonical

Tags: php, facebook, search-engine, facebook-opengraph, canonical-link

[I am implementing this method suggested by @Igy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152342/5525721) because I'm migrating a site from HTTP to HTTPS but would like to retain Facebook stats

My question is: since the HTTP version will have

```
<meta property="og:url" content="URI_FOR_HTTP_VERSION">
<link rel="canonical" href="URI_FOR_HTTPS_VERSION">
```

and the HTTPS version will have

```
<meta property="og:url" content="URI_FOR_HTTP_VERSION">
<link rel="canonical" href="URI_FOR_HTTPS_VERSION">
```

virtually identical metadata, both canonical pointers, but from Facebook's and search engine's respective POVs... will this cause an issue? since `<link rel="canonical">` is essential for search engine indexing..

Facebook issues these warnings for the HTTPS version:

> Mismatch og:url and canonical url  og:url tag in the header is not the same URL as rel='canonical' link in the html.

Would it hurt, if I leave off placing the rel=canonical tags and rely on og:url instead to just get rid of the warning OR ignore the warnings completely?

Comment: As long as it reads the meta data from the HTTP URL as intended, I think you can safely ignore this warning. For “normal” use cases that warning surely has its purpose - for a normal site, that has not been migrated from HTTP to HTTPS, this could likely just be a mistake on the webmaster’s part; but this here is an edge case that makes the two having different values necessary.